# how to move data from one column to another column's row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following DataFrame

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | row | row | row |
| Second | row | row | row | row |

beacuse my dataframe can be longer, I want to rename first 3 columns, and then I want the rows for the next 3 columns, to be dropped as a row for the first column

```
df.rename(columns={0:'data', 1:'user', 2:'file')
```

| data | user | file | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dataa_1 | user_1 | file_1 | dataa_2 | user_2 | file_2 |
| Second | row | row | row | row | row |

and then I want to write some code, so the rest of 3 column's row would be moved as a second row of my first column:

| data | user | file | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dataa_1 | user_1 | file_1 | row | row | row |
| dataa_2 | user_2 | file_2 | row | row | row |

Comment: You can't have duplicate column names.

Comment: Oh you right @Michael
Then , can i drop next 3 column's row as a second row for the first column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([range(6),range(6)],columns = ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth','six'])
df2 = df[['fourth','fifth','six']]
df2 = df2.rename(columns = {'fourth':'first','fifth':'second','six':'third'})
df3 = pd.concat([df,df2])
```

For the following result

[image]